# Feature selection via RFE, MRMR, embeded methods and categorical features' impact

Tags: feature-selection, matlab, ensemble-learning

I am using ensemble-tree for regression (in Matlab) for my research. I have 22 features that includes 16 continuous (numerical) and 6 categorical variables. Categorical variables are based on time, which are: 24 hours (24 levels), weekdays (7 levels), months (12 levels), number of weeks (52 levels), weekend or weekday (2 levels).
I am trying to do the feature selection using various methods that are Recursive feature elimination (RFE), Recursive feature addition (RFA), MRMR ([fsrmrmr](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fsrmrmr.html#mw_66de8ae2-927b-4443-a2f1-3414b781b4dc)), and embedded method ([predictorImportance](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/compactregressionensemble.predictorimportance.html#bst1m5t-6) by [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/feature-selection.html)).

After applying these methods, I tried to compare the importance of features for each method. By doing so, order of categorical variables are significantly varies based on the method. In other word, some categorical features are very important in RFE and RFA, but they are the least important features in mrmr. For example, "week number"  with 52 levels is the second important feature in RFE, RFA but last important feature in MRMR. While, feature of "hour" with 24 levels is the third and fourth important feature in RFE/RFA and mrmr, respectively.

1. My question is that which method I should trust? Is this due to the fact that for RFE/RFA I used R-squared to find the best feature, while filter method uses other metrics?
2. Is there any source that I can study focusing the categorical impact on the feature importance?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Table that shows the ranks of features based on the method.
[image: Feature's rank from 1 (most important) to 22 (less important)]

ca